third normal form (3NF) in a database
Customers(ID, VName, NName, Street, City, Country, ZIP-Code)
FCustomers = {
    {ID} → {VName, NName, Street, City, Country, ZIP-Code},
    {Street, City, Country} → {ZIP-Code},
    {ZIP-Code} → {Country}
    }

That relation is in 2NF (2nd normal form), but not in 3NF because of {Street, City, Country} → {ZIP-Code} and {ZIP-Code} → {Country}.
How do I decompose to 3NF?
How can I connect them?
How do I avoid redundancy?
How do I optimise the database?
Is it possible that after decomposition this 3NF case will also be BCNF?

Ask exactly 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Ask about how you are 1st stuck in a method/process/algorithm you give from a competent reference you give & give what steps you did so far following it.  PS Clearly all these questions will be duplicates and/or too vague/general and/or unclear. How  much research effort is
expected of Stack Overflow
users?

"How can I connect them?" What are "them" & what does "connect" mean & what does "connect them" mean? How are you 1st stuck doing that?
